# Do Partially Defined Entiy Classes in code-first approach work?

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I am using the code-first approach in Entity Framework 4.0. I have defined an entity class called 'Product' which contains these properties only - *ProductId, ProductName and ProductDescription*.

However, the table in database called 'Products' has additional columns like  *ProductAge, ProductWeight, ProductVolume and IsActive*. **Will updating/inserting using Entity Framework code-first approach still work with a partially defined entity class?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trivial issue would be inserts to the table if the unmapped columns are not nullable. Otherwise inserts will work fine. Assuming you are not going to recreate the database from your code first model, it should work.